# mock objects null for spring service class unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have Spring Service class with multiple constructor:

```
@Service("async")
public class AsyncProcessor extends Processor {


    private final JobRunner JobRunner;

    private final ExecutorService executorService;

    @Autowired
    public AsyncProcessor(final MyRepo MyRepo,
                              final JobRunner JobRunner) {
        this(MyRepo, JobRunner, 1, 1, 60);
    }

    public AsyncProcessor(final MyRepo MyRepo,
                              final JobRunner JobRunner,
                              @Value("${processor.corePoolSize:1}") final int corePoolSize,
                              @Value("${processor.maxPoolSize:1}") final int maxPoolSize,
                              @Value("${processor.keepAliveTime:60}") final int keepAliveTime) {
        super(MyRepo);
        this.JobRunner = JobRunner;
        this.executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveTime, SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
    }
    
}
```

I am using Junit 5 to create a service test using mocked dependencies but tripping up with an error which I am not able to solve:

here is my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Mock
    private MyRepo repo;

    @Mock
    private JobRunner jobRunner;

    @Mock
    private ExecutorService executorServiceMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private AsyncProcessor processor = new AsyncProcessor(repo, jobRunner);

    @Test
    public void shouldSubmitTaskOnExecutor() {

    }
    
}
```

I am getting null on the mocked repo and job runner fields and don't know why.
The issue started when I added the second constructor with the additional spring property params.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you leave off the `new` with `@InjectMocks`? (I'm not familiar with the annotation-based mock instantiation; I avoid magic external integrations specifically because of weird problems like this and prefer to just call `mock`.)

Comment: either way same result. Because of multiple constructors, I used with new.

Comment: actually you're right, it doesn't trip without annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I think the new keyword is messing things up. Create a Spring @Configuration class which has a @Bean annotated method that returns the async processor generated from the newly added constructor. Your test can then autowire it, without the constructor call.

Comment: this is a common module project which gets injected into other projects. basically the idea is to enable other projects to create thisbean with their own custom poolsize, timeout etc for the executor service and call this second constructor. they can also choose the default which is first